# super keyword got strikethrough in my react application

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, constructor

I am making a authorisation login page and facing some issues.

this is the code, my super got strikethrough in react, pls help me to resolve it. Any idea would be helpful. Or any other syntax instead of the constructor method. I think the problem lies in the constructor

```
import React , { Component } from "react";
import fire from "./config/fire";

class Login extends Component{

    constructor(props)
{
    super(props);
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.signup = this.signup.bind(this);
    this.state={
        email : "",
        password : ""
    }
}

login(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    fire.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email,this.state.password).then((u)=>{
        console.log(u)
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    })
}
signup(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    fire.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email,this.state.password).then((u)=>{
        console.log(u)
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    })
}
handleChange(e){
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name] : e.target.value
    })
}
render()
{
    return(
        <div>
            <form>
                <input
                type="email"
                id="email"
                name="email"
                placeholder="enter email address"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                value={this.state.email}
                />
                <input
                name="password"
                type= "password"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                id="password"
                placeholder="enter password"
                value={this.state.password}
                />
                <button onClick={this.login}>Login</button>
                <button onClick={this.signup}>Signup</button>
            </form>

        </div>
    )
}
}
export default Login;
```

I've also attached the snapshot of the error part
[image: I've also attached the image]

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor doesn't need to know about your props. You can modify your code by replacing `super(props)` by `super()` and your `constructor(props)` by `constructor()`.

Comment: I did this, the strikethrough isn't going